# cannot add toggle class

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a toggle click event on my svg. But it always say "n" (cannot add class). Why the alert can't turn to "yes" even I click it twice?

```
$(evt.target).toggleClass("active");
var act = $(evt.target).hasClass("active");
if (act) {
  alert("yes");
} else {

  alert("n");
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nanadia/c48ef7mt/1/)**

Comment: Add your `html` (svg and etc..) and update what is `$(evt.target)`

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: @kitcat we need to know what evt.target is, can you pllease post html?

Comment: Add the HTML and the log of evt.target

Comment: here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nanadia/c48ef7mt/1/  I want to make it change the color when I click on the part of polygon @Pedram

Comment: @kitcat check this out [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c48ef7mt/2/) You forgot to include jQuery.

Comment: @Pedram thanks a lot :)

Comment: _"here's the fiddle..."_ is not how SO works. All relevant data has to be part of the question itself. A link to an external resource (buried anywhere in the comments) is not enough because not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.